# PySpark : Writing Kafka Topic to Console is Failing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

Am getting the messages from Kafka Topic and writing it to a console. Reading the messages is not an issue, am able to read the message and also print the schema. But when am trying to write it to a console, its failing. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Below is my code,

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder\
  .appName("Kafka Spark")\
  .config("spark.jars", "/C:/Hadoop/Spark/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0- 10_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar")\
  .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/C:/Hadoop/Spark/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar")\
  .config("spark.executor.extraLibrary", "/C:/Hadoop/Spark/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar")\
  .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/C:/Hadoop/Spark/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar")\
  .getOrCreate()


dataFrameRead = spark\
    .readStream\
    .format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
    .option("subscribe", "Jim_Topic")\
    .load()

dataFrameRead.printSchema()

dataFrameConsole = dataFrameRead.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")\
    .writeStream.outputMode(outputMode='Append').format('console').start()

dataFrameConsole.awaitTermination()
```

Below is the error,

```
C:\Users\Macaulay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/Macaulay/PycharmProjects/Spark/KafkaSpark/KafkaTopic2CSV.py
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
+---+-----+

20/06/14 12:19:18 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPoolConfig
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$.<init>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:607)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$.<clinit>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchPartitionReader.<init>(KafkaBatchPartitionReader.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchReaderFactory$.createReader(KafkaBatchPartitionReader.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD.compute(DataSourceRDD.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$2092/833428682.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPoolConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
20/06/14 12:19:18 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
20/06/14 12:19:18 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source write support org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWrite@4ad854a4 is aborting.
20/06/14 12:19:18 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source write support org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWrite@4ad854a4 aborted.
20/06/14 12:19:18 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 39f99b61-806b-45da-b717-09a635405011, runId = 1022045a-8a75-4b25-ad41-328cbedcbfc4] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.doExecute(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$Lambda$1634/675684139.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$Lambda$1658/109672489.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3482)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collect$1(Dataset.scala:2812)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$Lambda$1614/1023696801.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3472)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$Lambda$1615/1752721246.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$4(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$$Lambda$1598/813934425.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3468)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2812)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$Lambda$1591/1450070714.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$4(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$$Lambda$1598/813934425.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$15(MicroBatchExecution.scala:551)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$Lambda$1590/1332436953.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:551)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$Lambda$1250/619118163.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$Lambda$1248/527271024.apply$mcZ$sp(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:244)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, BLR-MOB0161.sst.stp, executor driver): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPoolConfig
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$.<init>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:607)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$.<clinit>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchPartitionReader.<init>(KafkaBatchPartitionReader.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchReaderFactory$.createReader(KafkaBatchPartitionReader.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD.compute(DataSourceRDD.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$2092/833428682.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPoolConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1989)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1977)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$Lambda$2344/77762193.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$Lambda$2342/1283673514.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2155)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2144)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:758)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:376)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPoolConfig
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$.<init>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:607)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$.<clinit>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchPartitionReader.<init>(KafkaBatchPartitionReader.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchReaderFactory$.createReader(KafkaBatchPartitionReader.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD.compute(DataSourceRDD.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$2092/833428682.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPoolConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Hadoop\Spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 98, in deco
  File "C:\Hadoop\Spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o55.awaitTermination.
: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Writing job aborted.
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 39f99b61-806b-45da-b717-09a635405011, runId = 1022045a-8a75-4b25-ad41-328cbedcbfc4]
Current Committed Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[Jim_Topic]]: {"Jim_Topic":{"2":582,"1":264,"0":470}}}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[Jim_Topic]]: {"Jim_Topic":{"2":583,"1":264,"0":470}}}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
WriteToMicroBatchDataSource ConsoleWriter[numRows=20, truncate=true]
+- Project [cast(key#7 as string) AS key#21, cast(value#8 as string) AS value#22]
   +- StreamingDataSourceV2Relation [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13], org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaScan@1b90a9ca, KafkaV2[Subscribe[Jim_Topic]]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:244)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.doExecute(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$Lambda$1634/675684139.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$Lambda$1658/109672489.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3482)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collect$1(Dataset.scala:2812)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$Lambda$1614/1023696801.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3472)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$Lambda$1615/1752721246.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$4(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$$Lambda$1598/813934425.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3468)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2812)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$Lambda$1591/1450070714.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$4(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$$Lambda$1598/813934425.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$15(MicroBatchExecution.scala:551)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$Lambda$1590/1332436953.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:551)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$Lambda$1250/619118163.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$Lambda$1248/527271024.apply$mcZ$sp(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:332)
    ... 1 more

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Macaulay/PycharmProjects/Spark/KafkaSpark/KafkaTopic2CSV.py", line 22, in <module>
    dataFrameConsole = dataFrameRead.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")\
  File "C:\Hadoop\Spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\streaming.py", line 103, in awaitTermination
  File "C:\Hadoop\Spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1285, in __call__
  File "C:\Hadoop\Spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 102, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: Writing job aborted.
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 39f99b61-806b-45da-b717-09a635405011, runId = 1022045a-8a75-4b25-ad41-328cbedcbfc4]
Current Committed Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[Jim_Topic]]: {"Jim_Topic":{"2":582,"1":264,"0":470}}}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[Jim_Topic]]: {"Jim_Topic":{"2":583,"1":264,"0":470}}}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
WriteToMicroBatchDataSource ConsoleWriter[numRows=20, truncate=true]
+- Project [cast(key#7 as string) AS key#21, cast(value#8 as string) AS value#22]
   +- StreamingDataSourceV2Relation [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13], org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaScan@1b90a9ca, KafkaV2[Subscribe[Jim_Topic]]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I wonder why you don't use `pyspark` to submit the pyspark app for execution (but used `python.exe` instead)? Did you `pip install pyspark` (as per the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications))?

Comment: Yes i have installed pyspark. And am able to execute and read the messages from kafka source. But am unable to print it on the console. If you could see the output, am even able to print the schema. Since am defining the jars in the config, i don't require to execute as spark submit

Comment: @JimMacaulay I'm having the same problem. Did you find any workaround?

Comment: Hi @JimMacaulay, I am facing exactly same error "Writing job aborted", Did you find any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the commons-pool2 jar.   Linux version of the session builder config is:

```
sparkSesh = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/home/ubuntu/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2.jar,/home/ubuntu/jars/commons-pool2-2.11.0.jar")\
etc.
```

You can find that here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2/2.11.0